# Filter query set using Django rest serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two serialiser and one of them is used in another.

```
class CommentSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['id','text', 'author','approved' , 'created_date']
        read_only_fields = ['author' ,'approved' ,'created_date']
```

and then

```
class PostSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    comments = CommentSerializers(source='comment_set', many=True, read_only=True)
    post_media = PostMediaSerializers(source='postmedia_set', many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'id', 'text', 'likes_count', 'likes_count',
            'post_media', 'author', 'approved', 'comments','created_date',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['author', 'approved', 'comments','created_date',]
```

As you see I get comments on a post and I nest it there so that every post comes with its comments. The challenge is getting is that I only wanted to show users approved posts. How can I filter the comments_set?

Comment: If you don't need unapproved comments at all you should filter out them on a query level (e.g. with Prefetch object). Otherwise you can create model method that only takes a self argument and returns target comments, then use its name as a source attribute for your comment serializer.

Comment: That happens in views? right? The issue here is that the PostSerialiser doesn't;t use the CommentViews if I use it's serializer

Comment: There is no need for filtering comments if you are sending approved post to serializer then approved post show

Comment: So how do I exactly send only approved posts to a nested serialiser?